# Try to make mock test, but there is a loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, loops, unit-testing, mockito

Try to write mock test, but there is a 'for' loop which goes through map keys. How could I initialise map at test method.

**Test.java**

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class CartRecordServiceTest {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Mock
    private CartRecord cartRecords;
    @Mock
    private GoodsService goodsService;
    @Mock
    private GoodsRepository goodsRepository;

    CartRecordService cartRecordService;


    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        cartRecordService = new CartRecordService(cartRecords, goodsRepository, goodsService);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(cartRecordService)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkAvailableTest() {
        Map<Long, Long> records = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L));

        Mockito.when(goodsService.enoughQuantity(any())).thenReturn(true);

        Assertions.assertTrue(cartRecordService.checkAvailable());

        verify(goodsService, times(2)).enoughQuantity(any());
    }
}
```

**Method.java**

```
@Service
public class CartRecordService {
    private final CartRecord cartRecords;
    private final GoodsRepository goodsRepository;
    private final GoodsService goodsService;

    public CartRecordService(CartRecord cartRecord, GoodsRepository goodsRepository, GoodsService goodsService) {
        this.cartRecords = cartRecord;
        this.goodsRepository = goodsRepository;
        this.goodsService = goodsService;
    }

    public boolean checkAvailable(){
//here is map
        final Map<Long, Long> records = cartRecords.getRecords();
        for(Long id : records.keySet()){
            if(!goodsService.enoughQuantity(new CartAdditionDTO(id, records.get(id)))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Log says:
Wanted but not invoked:
goodsService.enoughQuantity();
-> at com.example.store.ServiceUnitTests.CartRecordServiceTest.checkAvailableTest(CartRecordServiceTest.java:117)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
goodsService.enoughQuantity();
-> at com.example.store.ServiceUnitTests.CartRecordServiceTest.checkAvailableTest(CartRecordServiceTest.java:117)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mocking your `getRecords()` on `CartRecord` Class

```
Map<Long, Long> records = new HashMap<>(Map.of(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L));
Mockito.when(cartRecords.getRecords()).thenReturn(records);
```